# How to take two similar table columns' values into one table using SELECT INTO?

Tags: mysql

I would like to take two table values into one table by using `SELECT INTO`. Those two tables are similar in columns.

The query I usually use to take one table backup is:

```
SELECT * INTO tabel_backup FROM table(nolock)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build up your `SELECT` as if you were ignoring the fact it's being `INSERT`ed; something like this:

```
SELECT  table1.somefield,
        table2.another

INTO    tabel_backup

FROM    table1,
        table2

WHERE   table1.id = table2.id
```